# Why Is The Reptile Opposed To The Shawl?

Tags: riddle

> Why Is The Reptile Opposed To The Shawl?
>
> Why Are Both Far From The Urban Sprawl?
>
> One Gave Birth To Judah’s Master,
>
> The Other Calls Out To Avoid Disaster….

Clue #1: The answer will come from Europe

Clue #2: They used to say the Vikings named one after a bird resting place

Clue #3: Up & down

Clue #4: Where it was always completely dark and full of light

More clues:

- it is not related to Odin's ravens nor super weapon.
- Clue 2 relates to only one of the two from the riddle
- It is not from Norse mythology
- It does refer to the real historical Vikings
- Shawl IS a piece of clothing

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: btw its Norse mythology, not "Viking" mythology. Vikings were Norse fighters. Odin, Thor, Ragnorak, etc are part of NORSE mythology.

Comment: Sorry, fixed - Wasn't my clues :-P

Comment: If they're not your clues, you should credit the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was 'Lizard and Skarfskerry'

Reptile – Lizard.

Shawl – Scarf.

Opposed – Opposites.

Far from the urban sprawl – Remote.

Lizard – Southernmost settlement on
mainland GB.

Scarfskerry – Northernmost settlement on
mainland GB.

One gave birth…. – 19th century Sea Master
(captain) of “Maid of Judah”, James
Bremner, was born in Scarfskerry.

The other… - Famous fog horn at Lizard
Head.

Answer (score 1):

I'm far from certain, especially since my connections draw more from the hints than from the actual riddle, but I'll hazard a guess. Perhaps someone can build off my guess. The riddle refers to:

> Easter eggs.

---

"Why Is The Reptile Opposed To The Shawl?"

> ?

"Why Are Both Far From The Urban Sprawl?"

> Egg farms and Easter Island are far from urban centres.

"One Gave Birth To Judah’s Master,"

> Easter celebrates Jesus's rebirth.

"The Other Calls Out To Avoid Disaster…."

> ?

"The answer will come from Europe"

> ?

"They used to say the Vikings named one after a bird resting place"

> Egg in Old Norse is *hreiðr-bǫllr*, which literally means "nest-ball"

"Up & down"

> Refers to the ascent and return of Jesus? Or to the addling of an egg?

Where it was always completely dark and full of light

> Being an enclosed body, the egg is dark inside. However, the word for egg white in some languages (e.g. Spanish *clara*) is the same as the word for light (as in light-coloured or well illuminated).

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is an incomplete answer and is posted in hope that this helps someone figure out this riddle (as I am currently tunnel-visioned on Norse mythology even though there is a clue that literally states the opposite...)

Feel free to edit, add, or remove. I spent way too much time on this already :)

The answer may be one of the following:

> [The Norse Constellations](http://timothystephany.com/constellations.html) (or zodiac signs), the planets in our solar system, or Heaven & Hell

Why Is The Reptile Opposed To The Shawl?

> **Constellations:** The constellation Nidhogg is a serpent 
>  **Planets:** [Lucifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer) refers to the devil or the planet Venus when appearing as a morning star 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** This possibly refers to Judas being a traitor or a *snake*. Other possibility is a version of the betrayal of Jesus where the motive for betrayed was not just for money, but instead the [devil possessing Judas and offering him to betray Jesus](http://timothystephany.com/constellations.html). Some of the forms that the Devil takes is that of a serpent or dragon, both being reptiles. Jesus is from heaven; Devil lives in Hell. Jesus's robes look similar to a shawl.

Why Are Both Far From The Urban Sprawl?

> **Constellations:** Far away from Earth 
>  **Planets:** Far away from Earth 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** Far from urban sprawl because you need to perish to enter either

One Gave Birth To Judah’s Master,

> **Constellations:** ?? 
>  **Planets:** ?? 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** The Devil is a fallen angel from heaven who again entered Judas (another name for Judah) therefore becoming his 'master' **or** Jesus came from Heaven (both a stretch)

The Other Calls Out To Avoid Disaster….

> **Constellations:** ?? 
>  **Planets:** ?? 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** Heaven is good and Hell is evil

Clue #1: The answer will come from Europe

> **Constellations:** The Norsemen were originally from [Scandinavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norsemen) 
>  **Planets:** Possible relation to origins of astronomy? (stretch) 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** Heaven & Hell is a concept of Christianity which [originated in Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity)

Clue #2: They used to say the Vikings named one after a bird resting place

> **Constellations:** Bit of a stretch but the Norsemen though the night sky was [Yggdrasil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yggdrasil) where the rooster [Víðópnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%AD%C3%B0%C3%B3pnir) rested (except it goes back into mythology again...)  
>  **Planets:** ?? 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** The rooster [Gullinkambi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullinkambi) lives in [Valhalla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valhalla) which can be related to Heaven (again mythology...)

Up & down

> **Constellations:** You look up to see constellations but as the Earth rotates they will eventually be underneath the Earth (??) 
>  **Planets:** ?? 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** Trivial

Where it was always completely dark and full of light

> **Constellations:** The night sky is dark but constellations are made of stars which are full of light 
>  **Planets:** Space is dark (??) 
>  **Heaven & Hell:** Heaven is full of light, hell is dark

Another possible answer may be

> Days of the week

Comment: The line that says "One gave birth to Judah's master" could be related to the Star of Bethlehem. Jesus Christ was born from the tribe of Judah... maybe this will relate to your theory?